# Writing interrupt-driven I/O in C on COM1, output interrupts are triggering just fine but keyboard input never triggers an interrupt. Why?

Tags: c, x86, operating-system, driver, uart

I'm working with simple operating system concepts, and currently working on writing a simple interrupt-driven serial driver in C. I have serial writing down, triggering interrupts when it's supposed to and printing the entire message, but keyboard input is never triggering an interrupt, and I cant continue debugging the rest of my interrupt handler if I never enter the ISR.

Here's my port configurator routine (I imagine this routine is probably the problem):

```
int serial_open(device dev, int speed) {
    if (dev_pointers[serial_devno(dev)] != NULL) {
        return -103;
    }

    int valid = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (speed == valid_speeds[i]) {
            valid = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!valid) {
        return -102;
    }
    
    dcb* temp = sys_alloc_mem(sizeof(dcb));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        return -101;
    }

    temp->port = serial_devno(dev);
    temp->port_stat = 1;
    temp->alloc_stat = 0;
    temp->event_flag = 0;
    temp->current_op = 0;
    temp->head = 0;
    temp->tail = 0;
    temp->counter = 0;
    temp->buffer = NULL;
    temp->io_head = NULL;
    memset(temp->ring_buf, '\0', sizeof(temp->ring_buf));
    initialized[serial_devno(dev)] = 1;
    dev_pointers[serial_devno(dev)] = temp;

    if (dev == COM1) {
        idt_install(0x24, serial_isr);
    } else if (dev == COM2) {
        idt_install(0x23, serial_isr);
    } else if (dev == COM3) {
        idt_install(0x24, serial_isr);
    } else if (dev == COM4) {
        idt_install(0x23, serial_isr);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }

    int brd = 115200 / (long) speed;
    int rem = 115200 % (long) speed;
    outb(dev + IER, 0x00);
    outb(dev + LCR, 0x80);
    outb(dev + DLM, (uint8_t) rem);
    outb(dev + DLL, (uint8_t) brd);
    outb(dev + LCR, 0x03);

    cli();
    int mask = inb(0x21);
    if (dev == COM1 || dev == COM3) {
        mask = mask & ~0x10;
    } else if (dev == COM2 || dev == COM4) {
        mask &= 0x08;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
    outb(0x21, mask);
    sti();

    outb(dev + MCR, 0x08);
    outb(dev + IER, 0x01);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's my enum for register values:

```
enum uart_registers
{
    RBR = 0, // Receive Buffer
    THR = 0, // Transmitter Holding
    DLL = 0, // Divisor Latch LSB
    IER = 1, // Interrupt Enable
    DLM = 1, // Divisor Latch MSB
    IIR = 2, // Interrupt Identification
    FCR = 2, // FIFO Control
    LCR = 3, // Line Control
    MCR = 4, // Modem Control
    LSR = 5, // Line Status
    MSR = 6, // Modem Status
    SCR = 7, // Scratch
};
```

Here's my ISR (in x86 assembly):

```
bits 32
global serial_isr

extern serial_interrupt
serial_isr:
call serial_interrupt
iret
```

Here's my first-level handler (not sure if this matters but I figure'd I'd include it just in case):

```
void serial_input_interrupt(dcb* dcb) {
    char c = inb(dev_id(dcb->port) + RBR);
    outb(dev_id(dcb->port), c);
    if (dcb->current_op != READ) {
        if (dcb->head != dcb->tail) {
            dcb->ring_buf[dcb->head] = c;
            if (dcb->head + 1 >= 16) {
                dcb->head = 0;
            } else {
                dcb->head++;
            }
        } else {
            (void) c;
        }
    } else {
        if (dcb->io_head->op == dcb->current_op && dcb->io_head->buf_index < dcb->io_head->buf_size) {
            dcb->io_head->buf[dcb->io_head->buf_index] = c;
            if (dcb->counter > 0 && c != 10) {
                return;
            } else {
                dcb->event_flag = 1;
                dcb->current_op = IDLE;
            }
        }
    }
```

I can include my second-level handlers as well, just let me know if they're needed.

I've placed a breakpoint in the first-level handler, to ensure that the ISR is never entered (it never breaks), which I'm inferring means that interrupts are never triggered (please let me know if this inference is incorrect).

I've also tried the setting the MCR differently as well, and that hasn't worked.

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. The line `mask &= 0x08;` seems wrong (the `return -1` just below, after a `cli` seems even more wrong). I also don't see the code for the EOI in the ISR. Since you have a debugger set up (that's a very good thing), step over each line and check the PIC and the UART registers have the expected values. Also, check the ISR is working by invoking it via an `int` instruction and check the UART (emulation I suppose?) is working by polling for data/status.

Comment: This might help as well https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/8250_UART_Programming.

Comment: Thanks everyone for commenting. Turns out I was disabling all interrupts with cli(); elsewhere in the code then never reenabling them. My system is working correctly now.